# Usage of 〜するように

Tags: grammar, particles

I'm having a hard time figuring out the meaning of ように in

> ジャブー様の一件でもわかる**ように**
> ガノンは我々の行く手に
> 先手をうちはじめた

I know that when following a verb in dictionary form, ように can have several meanings, like "in order to", or when referring to orders, advice, etc. This usage doesn't seem to match anything I've learned so far though.

The English version translates this text as:

> Clearly, the search for Jabun has shown that Ganon
> has begun to make efforts to block our path forward.

Does the ように perhaps mean something like:

"In the manner/way we now understand (the situation) from the incident with Jabun"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically *like*, which is the most basic meaning of ようだ ([#1 and #2](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%A0/#jn-226613) rather than #4 and #5 for which ように is mentioned).

In terms of translation *as*: *As you see from...* Or *in the **similar** manner*...